# SUM(columnname) gives me a different result than manually summing columnname in SQL Server. Why?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Why is the SUM(Sold) giving me a different result than manually summing the field?

Here's the query that gives me the right # if I manually sum the Sold field:

```
SELECT     CustCode, FiscalYear, Sold 
FROM         DBNAME.dbo.SALESDETAIL
WHERE     (FiscalYear = YEAR({ fn NOW() }))
and CustCode = '248'
GROUP BY CustCode, FiscalYear, Sold
```

But if I try to use the SUM function, I get the wrong amount. Can anyone help me out?

```
SELECT     CustCode, FiscalYear, SUM(Sold) 
FROM         DBNAME.dbo.SALESDETAIL
WHERE     (FiscalYear = YEAR({ fn NOW() }))
and CustCode = '248'
GROUP BY CustCode, FiscalYear
```

The goal is that there is just one result returned- CustCode, FiscalYear, and Sum(Sold). Appreciate any pointers!

Comment: The first query eliminates duplicate `Sold` values. If you had two rows with the same `CustCode`,`FiscalYear`,`Sold`, the first query would return only one row while the second would sum the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CustCode, FiscalYear, Sold 
FROM DBNAME.dbo.SALESDETAIL
WHERE (FiscalYear = YEAR({ fn NOW() }))
  AND CustCode = '248'
GROUP BY CustCode, FiscalYear, Sold;
```

is the same as

```
SELECT  DISTINCT CustCode, FiscalYear, Sold 
FROM DBNAME.dbo.SALESDETAIL
WHERE (FiscalYear = YEAR({ fn NOW() }))
  AND CustCode = '248';
```

basically you get rid off multiple `Sold` values.

Try summing:

```
SELECT CustCode, FiscalYear, Sold 
FROM DBNAME.dbo.SALESDETAIL
WHERE (FiscalYear = YEAR({ fn NOW() }))
  AND CustCode = '248';
```

and compare with `SUM(Sold)` result.

Answer (score 1):

The first query groups by `CustCode`, `FiscalYear`, and `Sold`. I.e., it returns **one** row per unique combination of these fields. This means that if you have several entries for the same `CustCode` and `FiscalYear` that have the same `Sold`, you'll only return one of these rows, and lose the duplicates. Therefore, your manual summing is missing values, which the second query does not miss.